# scala cats readerT nest monad transformer could not find implicit parameter

Tags: scala, monads, monad-transformers, scala-cats

`cats.data.ReaderT[F[_], A, B]` of `F[_]` when used monad transformer.
to be missed implicit value `Monad[ReaderT[F, A, ?]]`.

```
scala> import cats._, cats.data._, cats.implicits._
import cats._
import cats.data._
import cats.implicits._

scala> implicitly[Monad[ReaderT[OptionT[List, ?], String, ?]]]
<console>:21: error: could not find implicit value for parameter e: cats.Monad[[γ$1$]cats.data.Kleisli[[β$0$]cats.data.OptionT[[+A]List[A],β$0$],String,γ$1$]]
       implicitly[Monad[ReaderT[OptionT[List, ?], String, ?]]]
                 ^
```

but. in order define type alias.
that way find implicit value.

```
scala> type OptionList[A] = OptionT[List, A]
defined type alias OptionList

scala> type OptionListReader[A] = ReaderT[OptionList, String, A]
defined type alias OptionListReader

scala> implicitly[Monad[OptionListReader]]
res1: cats.Monad[OptionListReader] = 
cats.data.KleisliInstances0$$anon$2@21898c8a
```

do can locate implicit value without defined type alias?